# Need help for get string in java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

I want get first name when input the name with array and looping

**Example** :

> ```
> Enter the name :
>
> 1. Alvin Indra
> 2. Sada Rika
> ```

**Output** :

> ```
> 1. Alvin
> 2. Sada
> ```

**Code**:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n;
    String teman[],namadepan[];
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Put how many friends : ");
    n = sc.nextInt();

    teman = new String[n];
    namadepan = new String[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        System.out.print("Friend Of-"+(i+1)+" : ");
        teman[i] = x.nextLine();
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
    System.out.println("First Name : ");
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(teman[i] == ' '){ // this is where I need help
            System.out.println((i+1)+". "+teman[i].substring(0,i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this even compile? `teman[i] == ' '` is not a valid statement.

Comment: no this different :(

Comment: @Gendarme what would `if(teman[i] == ' ')` be doing in that case?

Comment: @ChitogeKirisaki what is `if(teman[i] == ' ')` meant for then? by the way it wouldn;t compile as already pointed.

Comment: emmm i want check if that space get the first name

Comment: My point is that you are not supposed to compare strings. Even if you could compare strings with `==` the code would still make no sense - so it is not a duplicate question.

Comment: Agreed, probably just checking for the existence shall help and then doing s substring should work in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go

```
String name = "John Smith";
System.out.println(name.split(" ")[0]);
```

Using this will replace that second for loop, you don't need to cycle through each letter to look for a space you can just use the split method on the string and specifiy the character in which to split the string up and then call the first element.

## Updated complete implementation

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class testest {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int n;
        String teman[],namadepan[];
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Put how many friends : ");
        n = sc.nextInt();

        teman = new String[n];
        namadepan = new String[n];

        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            System.out.print("Friend Of-"+(i+1)+" : ");
            teman[i] = x.nextLine();
        }

        System.out.print("\n");

        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            System.out.println("First Name : ");
            System.out.println(teman[i].split(" ")[0]);
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No that can't i use array and input with scanner

Comment: @ChitogeKirisaki why can't you split into arrays?

Comment: He is saying that he wants to get input and not use `"John Smith"`. He is misunderstanding. @ChitogeKirisaki this answer is telling you to use [`String#split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) instead of using loops. He is not telling you to write the strings manually in your code. Using a scanner is fine.

Comment: Added full solution for you to show you how it should be implemented.

Comment: Can if use substring ? in first name ?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for using [`contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains-java.lang.CharSequence-) and [`indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-) methods of [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class in java, to use them as :

```
if (teman[i].contains(" ")) {
    System.out.println((i + 1) + ". " + teman[i].substring(0, teman[i].indexOf(" ")));
}
```